# Does Euclidean division not work for general polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

If $K$ is a field. Then in $K[X]$ there is  an Euclidean algorithm and if  $K$ is replaced by any arbitrary commutative ring $R$, then almost we have an Euclidean algorithm, by the following result:

> **Theorem:** Let $f,g\in R[X]$ be polynomials, and assume that the leading coefficient of $g$ is a unit in $R$. Then there exist unique polynomials $q,r\in R[X] $ such that 
>   $$f=gq+r$$ 
>   and $\deg(r)< \deg (g)$

If  $g$ is any arbitrary polynomial, is the conclusion of the theorem  false?

Thank you all.

Comment: ED implies PID. But only polynomials of one variable can form a PID. So no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conclusion of the theorem for arbitrary $g$ is false for example for $R=\mathbb{Z}$, indeed for any domain that is not a field.
Consider $f=X$ and $g=2X$, or generally $f=X$ and $g = aX$ where $a$ is not invertible.